# Migração de dados postgresql reformular tabela

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-jpa

O titulo pode dar a entender que estou recriando uma tabela com atributos semelhantes, mas o senário é o seguinte:

Tenho um banco de dados atualmente rodando na minha aplicação para fins de estudos, existe uma classe chamada PROPRIEDADE nela consta endereço(rua,cidade,numero)/contato(email,telefone)/nome do proprietário,entre outros dados que são de fato dela, isto está dentro do meu banco de dados em uma tabela de mesmo nome com todos os dados nela, resumidamente foi criado através do spring , mas como se pode perceber o ideal seria por exemplo o Endereço em uma outra tabela, esta tabela PROPRIEDADE já esta populada com dados, gostaria de saber se é possivel "arrumar" o banco e migrar os dados das colunas referete a endereço (rua, cidade, numero) para uma outra tabela, quem sabe migrar as colunas num todo utilizando o Hibernate

Comment: Se entendi sua dúvida talvez um INSERT INTO sua_nova_tabela SELECT campos FROM sua_tabela_original; . Talvez a cláusula ON CONFLICT possa ser útil.

Comment: Entendo, eu gostaria de fazer esta migração pelo Hibernate ou quem sabe Flyway